# how can I effect DNS Caching on PHP/Memcache application

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, php, memcached, internal-dns

In a very high loaded Ubuntu/PHP web server I found that the PHP line:

$memcache->connect("int-aws_ec2.memcached.myapp.net",11211);

sometimes takes ~5 secs.

Replacing the url with the ip address decreases the server load from ~20 to 0

My question is - where are the settings that effect the DNS caching for this? Is it in the server level or the memcache library ? How can I change it ?

Additional info:
Ubuntu 10.04 lucid
PHP: 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.10 
Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) 
Amazon EC2

Even more info per Celada's comment:

The DNS handling for the memcache server is done by scalr (the platform I use to manage the cloud resources). They have a client located on the instances and their own DNS servers.

/etc/nsswitch.conf - hosts:          files dns
/etc/resolv.conf:
nameserver 172.16.0.23
domain ec2.internal
search ec2.internal

The domain is not in hosts.conf
To check if I run nscd I used /etc/init.d/nscd stop and received 'no such file' so i guess I dont run nscd.

Thanks !

Comment: What are your hostname resolution settings ("hosts" line in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` and contents of `/etc/resolv.conf`)? Are you using a local DNS (e.g. 127.0.0.1 in `/etc/resolv.conf`)? Does the hostname in question appear in `/etc/hosts`? Are you running `nscd`? By the way, the underscore character is not valid in host names.

Comment: Please see post edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing double buffering of the ip addresses in APC (PHP Cache) memory.
This solves all the DNS timing issues.